# Commerce connect EaStateCartRepository requirement for automation plans

Tags: sitecore-commerce

In the [commerce connect documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-commerce/storing-a-copy-of-the-cart-locally.html) it mentions use of the `EaStateCartRepository` and `EaStateSqlBasedCartRepository` for local persistence. But there is little information regarding if this is required should you wish to store user carts in `Marketing Automation`. If you wish to use `Marketing Automation` to store an abandoned cart for example, is the `EaStateCartRepository` still a requirement? Or is the logic to add a cart to an automation plan handled internally in the pipeline processors?

My initial understanding is that you still need the `EaStateCartRepository` and must add the relevant automation plan source to this repository for a cart to be added to an engagement plan in `Marketing Automation`, is this correct? If so, it seems that the `EaStateCartRepository`  will ALWAYS be required, even though the documentation states to not use this repository in production.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the details/history on `EaStateCartRepository`. But it looks the `EaStateCartRepository` is not enabled as the default settings from `Sitecore Commerce 10.2` (Commerce Connect is part of it). At the same time, the abandoned cart engagement plan is still working. So I'd guess this storing a copy of the cart locally (with the corresponding config changes) are not mandatory for MA to work.